# Why split points are out of order on Hadoop total order partitioner?

Tags: hadoop, split, mapreduce, partitioner

I use Hadoop total order partitioner and random sampler as input sampler.

But when I increase my slave nodes and reduce tasks to 8, I get following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Split points are out of order
```

I don't know the reason for this error.

How can I set the number of three parameters on `inputsampler.randomsampler` function?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible problems

- You have duplicate keys
- You are using a different comparator for the input sampler and the task on which you are running the total order partitioner

You can diagnose this by downloading the partition file and examining its contents. The partitions file is the value of `total.order.partitioner.path` if it is set or `_partition.lst` otherwise. If your keys are text, you can run `hdfs dfs -text path_to_partition_file | less` to get a look. This may also work for other key types, but I haven't tried it.

If there are duplicate lines in the partition file, you have duplicate keys, otherwise you're probably using the wrong comparator.

## How to fix

### Duplicate Keys

My best guess is that your keys are so unbalanced that an even division of records among partitions is generating partitions with identical split points.

To solve this you have several options:

- Choose a value to use as a key that better distinguishes your inputs (probably not possible, but much better if you can)
- Use fewer partitions and reducers (not as scalable or certain as the next solution, but simpler to implement, especially if you have only a few duplicates). Divide the original number of partitions by largest number of duplicate entries. (For example, if your partition key file lists: `a`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `c`, `c`, `d`, `e` as split points then you have 9 reducers (8 split points) and max duplicates of 3. So, use 3 reducers (3=floor(9/3)) and if your sampling is good, you'll probably end up with proper split points. For complete stability you'd need to be able to re-run the partition step if it has duplicate entries so you can guard against the occasional over-sampling of the unbalanced keys, but at that level of complexity, you may as well look into the next solution.
- Read the partitions file, rewrite it without duplicate entries, count the number of entries (call it `num_non_duplicates`) and use `num_non_duplicates+1` reducers. The reducers with the duplicated keys will have much more work than the other reducers and run longer. If the reduce operation is commutative and associative, you may be able to mitigate this by using combiners.

### Using the wrong comparator

Make sure you have `mapred.output.key.comparator.class` set identically in both the call to `writePartitionFile` and the job using `TotalOrderPartitioner`

## Extra stuff you don't need to read but might enjoy:

The `Split points are out of order` error message comes from the code:

```
  RawComparator<K> comparator =
    (RawComparator<K>) job.getOutputKeyComparator();
  for (int i = 0; i < splitPoints.length - 1; ++i) {
    if (comparator.compare(splitPoints[i], splitPoints[i+1]) >= 0) {
      throw new IOException("Split points are out of order");
    }
  }
```

The line `comparator.compare(splitPoints[i], splitPoints[i+1]) >= 0` means that a pair of split points is rejected if they are either identical or out-of-order.

1 or 2 reducers will never generate this error since there can't be more than 1 split point and the loop will never execute.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are generating enough keys?
From the javadoc: [TotalOrderPartitioner](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/TotalOrderPartitioner.html#setConf(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration))

The input file must be sorted with the same comparator and contain

```
JobContextImpl.getNumReduceTasks() - 1 keys.
```

Comment: Lack of keys would generate the error message: "Wrong number of partitions in keyset". This is not the problem.